# Correct way to write a simple LLVM Pass

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

This code snippet compiles and runs but I am not sure if I am understanding the LLVM IR correctly.

```
auto *alloca_instr = new AllocaInst(llvm::IntegerType::get(customcontext, 64), 0, "local_variable", &I);

Value *alloca_value = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt64Ty(customcontext), 4444);
auto *store_instr = new StoreInst(alloca_value, alloca_instr, &I);

llvm::Type *int_type = llvm::Type::getInt64Ty(customcontext);
auto *load_instr = new LoadInst(int_type, alloca_instr, "load_instr", &I);

BinaryOperator *add_numbers = BinaryOperator::Create(Instruction::Add, load_instr, load_instr, "custom_add", &I);
```

Am I right to say that

1. `local_variable` has the integer value 4444 after the `StoreInst` instruction
2. `load_instr` points to the value 4444 after the `LoadInst` instruction
3. `BinaryOperator` will add 4444 to itself (4444 + 4444)

The IR output I got from opt was:

```
%local_variable = alloca i64, align 8
store i64 4444, i64* %local_variable, align 8
%load_instr = load i64, i64* %local_variable, align 8
%custom_add = add i64 %load_instr, %load_instr
```

Comment: No offense but, is there a _question_ after all? Answering title's question, I think you should probably refer to the docs https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html

Comment: Hi @horro, I did refer to that article as well. I am just trying to understand if my understanding of the IR that was generated was correct.